# JPA ManyToMany persist

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, many-to-many, persist

I have a `NOTIFICATION` table who contains one ManyToMany association :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="NOTIFICATION")
@NamedQuery(name="Notification.findAll", query="SELECT f FROM Notification f")
public class Notification {

/** SOME COLUMN DEFINITION NOT IMPORTANT FOR MY CASE
    COD, DATE, ID_THEME, ID_TYP, IC_ARCH, ID_CLIENT, INFOS, NAME, TITRE_NOT, ID_NOT
**/

        @ManyToMany
        @JoinTable(
            name="PJ_PAR_NOTIF"
            , joinColumns={
                @JoinColumn(name="ID_NOTIF")
                }
            , inverseJoinColumns={
                @JoinColumn(name="ID_PJ_GEN")
                }
            )
        private List<PiecesJointesGen> piecesJointesGens;
}
```

So, I have an association table called `PJ_PAR_NOTIF`.

I try to persist a `Notification` entity. Here is piecesJointesGens initialisation, from a Value Object :

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName="pu/middle")

private EntityManager entityMgr;

FoaNotification lFoaNotification = new FoaNotification();

for(PieceJointeGenVO lPJGenVO : pNotificationVO.getPiecesJointes()){
        PiecesJointesGen lPiecesJointesGen = new PiecesJointesGen();
        lPiecesJointesGen.setLienPjGen(lPJGenVO.getLienPieceJointeGen());
        lPiecesJointesGen.setIdPjGen(lPJGenVO.getIdPieceJointeGen());
        lNotification.getFoaPiecesJointesGens().add(lFoaPiecesJointesGen);
}

entityMgr.persist(pNotification);
```

The persist doesn't work. JPA generate a first insert for my Notification object, that is ok :

```
insert 
into
    NOTIFICATION
    (COD, DATE, ID_THEME, ID_TYP, IC_ARCH, ID_CLIENT, INFOS, NAME, TITRE_NOT, ID_NOT) 
values
    (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Then, JPA try to insert values in my association table, but piecesJointesGen doesn't exists for the moment :

```
insert 
into
    PJ_PAR_NOTIF
    (ID_NOTIF, ID_PJ_GEN) 
values
    (?, ?)
```

So, I have this error :

```
GRAVE: EJB Exception: : java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: com.entities.PiecesJointesGen
```

Is there a way to tell JPA to insert `piecesJointesGen` before the `PJ_PAR_NOTIF` insert ?

Comment: Try using `@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)` on your `piecesJointesGens` mapping.

Comment: This is it ! Thanks @PredragMaric !

Comment: Great, I've added it as an answer since it helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify `piecesJointesGens` mapping to `@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)`.